# how to get ajax request response body using dotnetbrowser?

Tags: c#, ajax, dotnetbrowser

I have gone through the document on the dotnetbrowser website... while I saw an example that shows how to intersect Ajax calls or filter Ajax calls... I want to know if its possible to obtain Ajax request body response after execution. if it is possible how can I go about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to intercept the responses for the AJAX requests in DotNetBrowser. To implement this, you can use the `ResourceHandler` to capture AJAX request URLs and the `NetworkDelegate` to intercept and filter responses.

The following sample code demonstrates the possible approach:

```
using DotNetBrowser;
using DotNetBrowser.WinForms;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace GetAjaxResponseBodySample
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private static List<string> ajaxUrls = new List<string>();
        private WinFormsBrowserView browserView;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            browserView = new WinFormsBrowserView();
            browserView.Browser.Context.NetworkService.ResourceHandler = new AjaxResourceHandler();
            browserView.Browser.Context.NetworkService.NetworkDelegate = new AjaxNetworkDelegate();
            Controls.Add(browserView);
            browserView.Browser.LoadURL("http://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_examples.asp");
        }

        private class AjaxResourceHandler : ResourceHandler
        {
            public bool CanLoadResource(ResourceParams parameters)
            {
                if (parameters.ResourceType == ResourceType.XHR)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("Intercepted AJAX request: " + parameters.URL);
                    ajaxUrls.Add(parameters.URL);
                }
                return true;
            }
        }

        private class AjaxNetworkDelegate : DefaultNetworkDelegate
        {
            public override void OnDataReceived(DataReceivedParams parameters)
            {
                if (ajaxUrls.Contains(parameters.Url))
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("Captured response for: " + parameters.Url);
                    Debug.WriteLine("MimeType = " + parameters.MimeType);
                    Debug.WriteLine("Charset = " + parameters.Charset);
                    PrintResponseData(parameters.Data);
                }
            }

            private void PrintResponseData(byte[] data) {
                Debug.WriteLine("Data = ");
                var str = Encoding.Default.GetString(data);
                Debug.WriteLine(str);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: hello, I can't thank you well enough... your code is exactly what I needed. are you part of TeamDev? thanks very much.