# Can dotnetbrowser run on iis only?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, dotnetbrowser

Can https://www.teamdev.com/dotnetbrowser run on a IIS .NET server only? We want to:

1) Use ASP.NET to create a new thread upon a certain user action

2) load various DOMs from various external websites into instances if it

3) wait 30 seconds for each one so their image carousels can load up various images

4) inspect DOMs during that 30 second wait to see what new images get loaded via Ajax

5) record the URLs of those images

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use DotNetBrowser in IIS environment using the off-screen mode.

The next sample displays how to create basic ASP.NET controller that uses DotNetBrowser.

```
public class BrowserController : Controller
{
    private Browser dotNetBrowser;

    protected override void Initialize(RequestContext requestContext)
    {
        base.Initialize(requestContext);

        //Create off-screen browser instance
        dotNetBrowser = BrowserFactory.Create();

        //Subscribe to the web page loaded event
        dotNetBrowser.DocumentLoadedInFrameEvent += DotNetBrowser_DocumentLoadedInMainFrameEvent;
    }

    public ActionResult UrlHandle()
    {
        string url = "google.com"; //Set URL you need to load
        dotNetBrowser.LoadURL(url);

        return View();
    }

    private void DotNetBrowser_DocumentLoadedInMainFrameEvent(object sender, FrameLoadEventArgs frameLoadEventArgs)
    {
        //Get image references from DOM
        IEnumerable<string> imageReferences = dotNetBrowser.GetDocument()
                                                           .GetElementsByTagName("img")
                                                           .Select(element => (element as DOMElement)?.Attributes["src"]);

        foreach (string imageReference in imageReferences)
        {
            //Do whatever you need
            Console.WriteLine(imageReference);
        }

        //Dispose browser instance after all required actions
        dotNetBrowser.Dispose();
    }
}
```

You can find useful information related to your goals by the following links:

Resource handling - https://dotnetbrowser.support.teamdev.com/support/solutions/articles/9000110154-handling-resources-loading

Ajax requests handling - [how to get ajax request response body using dotnetbrowser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42114104)